# Passing local variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Hi I have a rails 4 app where I have this code:

```
<%= form_for @store, do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
    <%= render "product_fields",  f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Product", f, :products  %>
<% end %>
```

and then I have **_product_fields.html.erb** like:

```
<%= f.select :type_of, %w[Blah blah], {}, class: "select_it" %>
<div class='product-view'>
   <%= render "stores/product_form/bookshelf", f:f %>
</div>
```

My javascript(coffeescript) looks like:

```
$('form').on 'change', '.select_it', (e) ->
   value = $(this).val()
   params = 'type=' + value
   $.ajax({
     url: "/switch_product",
     data: params
   })
```

Then my controller looks like:

```
def switch_product
  @type = params[:type]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and then I have a **switch_product.js.erb** file that looks like:

```
$(this).(".product-view").html("<%= j render "stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}", f:f %> ");
```

But on the switch_product.js.erb I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `f'
```

How do I pass a local variable from a page to a js.erb file?

EDIT:

Here's what I'm trying to render with switch_product.js.erb (but this is only one, I have _books.html.erb and _bookshelf.html.erb as well:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :the_type_is, value: "Birdhouse" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :product_fields, f.object.product_fields.build do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_area :price %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try like this `$(this).(".product-view").html("<%= j render "stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}", :locals => { :f => f } %>");`

Comment: @Pavan, Ok I tried it but I still get the same error?

Comment: At which line you are getting the error?

Comment: @Pavan, I have the Chrome Developer Tools up and on the network page for the switch_product.js.erb the entire file (just the line I posted) is errored out

Comment: This `".product-view"` should be `"#product-view"` i guess.

Comment: @Pavan, But wouldn't that be for an element with a id of product-view not a class?

Comment: Yes,you are right.But i guess you should try with passing some `id` to that `div` and like this `$(this).("some_id").html("<%= j render "stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}", :locals => { :f => f } %>");`

Comment: @Pavan, this is a good point, thanks. But it didn't resolve the error, unfortunately.

Comment: @infinity Can you post your `"stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}"` partial? what are you trying to do with `#{@type.downcase}`? You can't use a `this` either inside your js.erb file

Comment: @user2675613, I just posted it. Basically, when you change the select, it should render a different partial (could be bookshelf.html.erb or birdhouse.html.erb, or could something else). So with `stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}`, I basically am trying to make the value of the select (which is corresponding to the name of the partial the user wants to display), a valid partial name (because I have Bookshelf as the value name and stores/product_form/Bookshelf isn't valid, it has to be downcased to stores/product_form/bookshelf be a valid partial

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from this in your .js.erg:

```
  <%= j render "stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}", f:f %>
```

The `f:f` at the end. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I'm trying to pass a local variable to the rendered partial

Comment: I also tried doing it with `locals: { f:f }` but that didn't work either.

Comment: The problem is that `f` is not defined in the context you are referencing it. You are trying to pass in a hash with a single key/value, the key is the symbol `:f`, and the value is the variable `f`. But there is no variable `f` defined. Is that what you are trying to do? What do you expect the variable `f` to be defined as, and where was it defined?

Comment: It was defined in product_fields.html.erb which is rendered as a partial in _form.html.erb. When I click a select on _product_fields.html.erb, I want it to pass f to the .js.erb page

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `switch_product.js.erb` is rendered from a different controller action from the preceding files. If that's the case, this will not work. You're instantiating a builder during the HTML rendering in the first action, and once it's done rendering that page the builder has fallen out of scope and is delivered to the Ruby garbage collector.

You need to re-render the entire form, all the way up to the `<%= form_for @store, do |f| %>` stuff in your first file. You didn't provide the filename of that file so let's say that was `show.html.erb`.

What I'd do is basically move all of that to `_product_form.html.erb` (unless it's already a partial), and then change `switch_product.js.erb` to render that partial:

```
$(this).(".product-view").html("<%= j render(partial: 'product_form') %>");
```

Assuming that entire form was originally right under `.product-view`, it will replace your entire form. There may be some more detail work that's specific to your app, but this should put you on the right direction.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really following you. So your saying in product_fields.html.erb, I should move the form_for (its originally on my new.html.erb file) call to it?

Comment: Okay, I would move that form_for out of new.html.erb and into a partial called _product_form.html.erb. Then new.html.erb would just render(partial: 'product_form'), and switch.js.erb would do what I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to pass *a form builder inside a partial from your js.erb file*. You can't do this. When you submit your form through your ajax call the control moves to your ajax method inside controller and the **scope of form builder is also finished**.

If you look at your code in js.erb file:

```
$(this).(".product-view").html("<%= j render "stores/product_form/#{@type.downcase}", f:f %> ");
```

There are two issues:

a. `this` keyword has lost its scope so you can't use it here. To **fix** this you *need to specify an id or class* of that element

b. Your form builder `f` has lost its scope as well so *instead of rendering a part of your form you need to render the whole form itself*

*Instead of rendering this part*:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :the_type_is, value: "Birdhouse" %>
<%= f.fields_for :product_fields, f.object.product_fields.build do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_area :price %>
<% end %>
```

**You need to render this:**

```
<%= form_for @store, do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
    <%= render "product_fields",  f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Product", f, :products  %>
<% end %>
```